# Pine script how to exit all position if current price is %x below or up the Average of the all entries?

Tags: pine-script, cryptocurrency

I have a strategy  and make decision long / short.

long could be more then one entry as in short .

Before exit we could have multiply long / or multiply short order . How I can calculate all long or short and see if current price is %x below or up than exit ALL positions?

Best

Comment: There are `strategy.position_avg_price` https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#var_strategy{dot}position_avg_price. You can compare it with last price (`close`)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example to exit all position if price goes down a certain percentage of your average position average price.

```
longStop = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - 0.05)
if close < longStop
    strategy.close_all(comment = "close all entries")
```